# VncSharp dll does not contain user controls C#

Tags: c#, exception, vnc

I've just downloaded a VNC implemention from this reposity:
https://github.com/humphd/VncSharp

Now when i try to build and launch it im getting an exception

> C:\Users\itapi\Desktop\VncSharp-master\VncSharp\obj\Debug\VncSharp.dll' doesn't contain any UserControl types.

What does that mean? and why it's happening? i didnt realy touch it just downloaded and compiled... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your solution is set up with a library as the startup project. Visual Studio is trying to start a dll as the entry point of an application, and failing. It *is* possible to start libraries in the specific circumstance that they contain Windows Forms UserControls - in this case a simple container app that simply hosts the control is started.

Set the startup project to an executable to resolve this problem.

**edit:**

Hm, The VncSharp repo readme says:

> VncSharp is a VNC Client Library and custom Windows Forms Control.

In which case it is strange that the special condition I mentioned is not recognised. In any case, it still doesn't really make sense to try and run a library as an application.